# Routing proxied traffic though a squid proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have an application which runs on multiple servers all on different IPs. This application makes network requests using proxies. Each "account" that is used has an assigned proxy.

Each proxy is only allowed to be accessed from one IP.

What I would like to do is route all the traffic through a squid proxy on one main server (which is the one that is allowed by the proxy providers).

My question is - how can I do this AND still forward the traffic to the correct proxy?